# Why didn't Kabuto use Deidara more effectively?

Tags: naruto, retag

> Kabuto summoned Deidara during the fourth world war, but only used him to keep the Tsuchikage busy while he (Kabuto) kidnapped Yamato. He then unsummoned Deidara and has never summoned him since then. 
> Edo Tensei makes Deidara immortal, which allows Deidara to use the C0, a giant explosion that covers an area of 10 km diameter, several times. Kabuto could have used this to eliminate the enemy units more effectively, but why did he not do so?

Comment: I've added the [tag:retag] tag to this question. This tag should be used by new users when trying to add new tags, and should not be removed. Thus, I locked the post so that it does not get removed. I chose this post because it does not appear that newer and/or better answers can appear, and it does not appear to be editable into a question that may be a good fit for the site. If, by some reason, this is seen as wrong in some time in the future, let some mod know, so that we can unlock the post for whatever reasons seem necessary at that time. :)

Comment: Because this is a "special" question (it's the anchor question for [tag:retag]), I've [moved the comments to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58348/discussion-on-question-by-masked-man-why-didnt-kabuto-use-deidara-more-effectiv) and deleted them from this question to make JNat's comment above immediately visible. This is to help ensure that I or another moderator doesn't accidentally clear [tag:retag] off this question in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got your facts a bit wrong actually:

> He was actually summoned later, as a part of the Special Ops Batallion (or whatever the name may be), along with Sasori and Shin. They fought against Kankurou and Sai.
>  In that battle, he was sealed (along with Sasori) inside Kankurou's Kuroari. This, along with the fact that Kabuto was still testing the summoned ninja (since he still allowed them to retain their personalities and fighting style), is probably the reason why he was not used more effectively.

See [here](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Deidara#Shinobi_World_War_Arc) for more details.

Answer (score 3):

Kabuto *did* use him effectively. He just got captured very early into the war.